# loop to extract info from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

first i am a noob.i am writing a program that will give you relationship info for a child(mother,father,both parents). if you hit 1 it ask you for the childs name and then tell you the childs mothers name,2 same thing except the fathers name,3 will tell you both parents name, and 4 will stop the program. the dictionary is predetermined. this is the general idea

```
child2parents = {'andrew': {'father': 'john', 'mother': 'jane'}, 'betsy': {'father': 'nigel', 'mother': 'ellen'}, 'louise': {'father': 'louis', 'mother': 'natalie'}, 'chad': {'father': 'joseph', 'mother': 'mary'}}

x = ""

while x != 4:    
choice = int(raw_input("1 = mother, 2 = father 3 = both parents 4 = stop "))
if choice == 1:
    childs_name = raw_input("please enter childs name here ")
    for i in child2parents:
            if i == childs_name:
                print ['i']['mother']
```

i cant seem to make it work and havent taken the code any further because i cant get option 1 to work

Comment: Why do you use a loop? You have a dictionary, so you can access the value directly.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you don't need to iterate over the dictionary. Once you have the child name, you can use it to access the child's data with `child2parents[child_name]` or `child2parents.get(child_name)` (the latter will return None by default if the child_name is not found), e.g. if the user introduces 'andrew' as the child_name, you'll be returned another dictionary `{'father': 'john', 'mother': 'jane'}`.

So to get the 'mother' key of a child, you can use `child2parents[child_name]['mother']`.

In Python2.7, if you want to iterate over a dictionary, you can call `child2parents.iteritems()`, see [iteritems](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems).

Answer (score 0):

You're indexing `['i']` by `['mother']` but `['i']` is just a list containing the string `"i"` and you're not actually indexing the nested dictionary inside child2parents. `i` is a key inside child2parents upon each iteration. And then you're prompting for a child name which would be this key that you want to further index. I think you mean to use `child2parents[i]['mother']`

Comment: when i try that it says TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Comment: No problem. If this or any other answer answers your question please mark as accepted, so it's not shown in the feed as unanswered

Answer (score 0):

The first error in your program is that you cannot use a string as the index of List( in the print['i']['mother']) you must convert these indeces to integers or think about other ways. I wrote it like this:

```
child2parents = {'andrew': {'father': 'john', 'mother': 'jane'}, 'betsy': {'father': 'nigel',
                                                                           'mother': 'ellen'}, 'louise': {'father':
                                                                                                          'louis', 'mother': 'natalie'},
                 'chad': {'father': 'joseph', 'mother': 'mary'}}

x = ""

while x != 4:    
 choice = raw_input("Enter what information do you want(mother,father, parents)")
 childs_name = raw_input("please enter childs name here ")
 if choice =="parents":
        print choice+" of "+childs_name+ " is: " + child2parents[childs_name]['father']+","+child2parents[childs_name]['mother']  
 else:
        print choice+" of "+childs_name+ " is: " + child2parents[childs_name][choice]
```